# How to get rid of the pencil icon from Google Workspace Labs

Tags: google-docs

How do I get rid of this icon in Google Docs:

[image]

I believe I got sucked into this via an offer from The Google that I opted in to use, but silly me, I did not even consider that a billion-dollar corporation would not pay sufficient QA engineering salaries to catch egregious UX mistakes such as this, that **obscures the first character or two from the left edge**. The offer I'm referring to is:

[image]

Sure, you can say "Well, just opt out" and I likely will do that, but when I used the menu, `Tools` --> `Opt out of Labs`, it popped up with this:

[image]

Then clicking on that Learn more link, I got punished with this:

[image]

So that is the reason why I have to resort to posting here to plea for help to somehow workaround this issue while Google takes time to fix that problem.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the author asked for a workaround, yet when offered one they claimed they don't want a workaround. This question isn't really answerable otherwise as it depends on implementation by website owners.

Comment: It is also about a web app, not desktop software. It's also half rant.

Answer (score 1):

Via brute force:

1. (Shift+)Right-click the button, select "Inspect element", note down its class name and/or element name (go up through the element tree until you find the correct parent that represents the whole button).
2. Install the 'Stylus' browser extension.
3. Create a new stylesheet through Stylus, along the lines of:

   ```css
   div.some-class.some-other-class {
       display: none !important;
   }
   ```

Comment: No doubt that would work. However, I'd rather not have to configure a style sheet to workaround to an egregious UX bug that a deep-pocketed corporation such as Google should fix by themselves, and have to apply it on all Chrome instances I use. However, if I get desperate, I can apply that change.

Comment: You asked for a workaround, you got a workaround.